# Rails App: Missing template with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, handlers

My rails app uses a route called "four_oh_four" to provide a custom 404 page that uses the site's application layout to look nice.

I've started receiving the following errors:

```
Missing template info/four_oh_four with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"], :locale=>[:en, :en]}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I need to be doing to resolve this. Any ideas?

Here's what the controller looks like (nothing, really):

```
def four_oh_four
end
```

And here's the routes.rb:

```
match 'four_oh_four' => 'info#four_oh_four', :as => :four_oh_four
...
# Catch 404s
match '*path' => 'info#four_oh_four', :status => 404
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a file named "four_oh_four.html.erb" in your info dir. It could be mistyping error . Usually the 404 page is located in /public .

Comment: The file is there, and it works fine for normal 404s...in this case it looks like the problem is that it's throwing a 404 for an image rather than a page, and doesn't seem to be handling that correctly. Any idea how I can get these formats (e.g., "image/jpeg") working too?